# EJB Lookup inside SAR

Tags: ejb, mbeans, sar

My EAR contains an ejb file and a sar file. I cannot do a lookup on a deployed ejb bean inside of a MBEAN contained in the SAR file.

I am getting NameNotFoundException. How can I do a lookup in the ejb2x home interface  inside the mbean service (deployed via the sar file on the EAR)????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this issue as below:

1) The MBean could not locate que EJB in jndi tree because it was not referenced in the mbean declaration as a dependency. So, I did this:

```
<mbean code="app.SchedulerManager" name="Company:service=SchedulerManager">
   <depends>jboss.j2ee:module=my-ejb-jar.jar,service=EjbModule</depends>
</mbean>
```

2) I also declared the  in the META-INF/jboss.xml of the ejb jar so that the dependency can be found:

```
<jmx-name>jboss.j2ee:module=my-ejb-jar.jar,service=EjbModule</jmx-name>
```